# Facebook login - curl error 7

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-login

I have two websites, in the same server, and the facebook API 3.2.3 (PHP) is not working anymore. It was working last night but it isnt now.

When I try to login in one of the sites it shows:

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://graph.facebook.com:443 (connection time-out)
```

the other one:

```
CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host
```

So,

I tried to change one of them from server: the error continues.
I tried to create a new app and try a different APP ID: the error continues.
I used the example code from Facebook API Page: The error continues
require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';

```
  require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'MY APP ID',
    'secret' => 'MY APP SECRET',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>
```

I dont know what is happening.

Comment: Check Facebook API changes in Facebook developer page. They keep constantly changing their API.

Comment: they don´t "keep constantly changing their API", they just improve it. but the basic principle with CURL is the same since years.

Comment: maybe it´s this one: https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10152444066278553

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses...  The Support of my host said that one IP had been blocked... so, they unblock it and now it is working! Thank you.